# Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Issue with adding Member to group in Azure AD, getting this error message:

> Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered
>   Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration

I am trying to add existing member of azure AD to a existing group,But I am getting response as "Bad Request". For some of the calls updateasync worked fine but member not added to group. I have provided my code that I am trying with the error I am getting below.Kindly suggest if any one has faced the same and resolved it.Thanks.

Code:-

```
 IUser newUser = await GetUser(userKey);
                Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group retrievedGroup = new Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group();
                List<IGroup> foundGroups = null;
                foundGroups = adClient.Groups
                         .Where(group => group.DisplayName.StartsWith(groupName))
                         .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList();
                if (foundGroups != null && foundGroups.Count > 0)
                {
                    retrievedGroup = foundGroups.First() as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;
                }
                if (retrievedGroup.ObjectId != null)
                {
                    retrievedGroup.Members.Add(newUser as DirectoryObject);
                    await retrievedGroup.UpdateAsync();
                }
```

Error:-

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration."},"date":"2016-10-18T08:02:22","requestId":"c757689c-6135-4198-9e4d-6a7aaa1135e7","values":null}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description and error message, you were using Azure Graph client to add members to group which created on-premises. This is expected, it is not able to update these objects which synced from on-premises to Azure AD.

To add members for this kind group, we need to operate it in the on-premises environment and then sync it to Azure.

### Update

Create a group and add the members using Azure AD Graph client:

```
var client = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient();

var group = new Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group();
group.DisplayName = "newGroup";
group.MailNickname = "newGroup";
group.MailEnabled = false;
group.SecurityEnabled = true;
await client.Groups.AddGroupAsync(group);

var newGroup = client.Groups.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First(a => a.DisplayName == "newGroup") as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;

var user = client.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First(u => u.DisplayName == "user2") as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.DirectoryObject;

group.Members.Add(user);
await group.UpdateAsync();


public static ActiveDirectoryClient CreateGraphClient()
{
        string accessToken = "";
        string tenantId = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"; 
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

        Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
        Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

        return activeDirectoryClient;
}
```

Comment: Hi Fei, Thanks for your comment,Do you say graph API can only update user which has directly created at Azure AD? would like to know if any alternate other than graph API or can I able to create group using graph api and assign user to it? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Yes. The graph API only able to update the object created on Azure AD. Yes the Graph API can create groups and assign users, you may refer the detail about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog). And I also write a code sample using Azure Graph client to create a group and add the members to this group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answer.I have created a group through graph API and added user to the group successfully.But need to look for the solution for the groups which created on-premise and synced with Azure AD.