# Set-AzureADuser failing

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory

Trying to streamline our MFA process by manually uploading the -Mobile attribute to Azure in powershell, so that when the user goes to do MFA, it's already filled in.

`Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $emailaddress -Mobile $cellphone`

This actually worked before, but now all of a sudden I'm getting

```
Set-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing SetUser 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory 
Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration.
```

We're in a hybrid environment with a one-way sync, and the "mobile" attribute is not a synced attribute for us. We set it for a few test users in AD, but it never made it to Azure. So we were doing it this way until this showed up all of a sudden. We haven't made any changes to our sync settings.

Microsoft documentation on doing exactly what I'm doing doesn't show me doing anything wrong.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Not sure why, since `Set-AzureADuser` worked before, but `Set-MsolUser` worked, and was able to update the mobile phone number. When I ran `Get-AzureADuser`, the number changed by `Set-MsolUser` was present.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description and error message, you were using Powershell to update members which were synced from on-premises. **This is expected, it is not able to update these objects which synced from on-premises to Azure AD.**

To update these type of users, we need to operate it in the on-premises environment and then sync it to Azure. **Try changing it on On-prem server and then sync it to Azure AD.**

Reference issues:

- [Getting "Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration" error message when updating a room mailbox contact informations on Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/106279/getting-34unable-to-update-the-specified-propertie.html)
- [Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102799/unable-to-update-the-specified-properties-for-on-premises-mastered-directory-syn)

Comment: I mean, that's not true. We've done it before with zero issue, with users that were synced from Azure AD. I have screenshots to back that up because we made documentation for other team members to do exactly that lol. I actually figured out how to do it in powershell using msolservice