# Unable to update Azure AD user property from SharePoint using @pnp/graph

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api, pnp-js, sharepointframework

I have created a SharePoint Framework web part using React. After that, I integrated @pnp/graph under that SPFx application. Also, I have given an API access permission request to my SPFx app.

I have fetched all users from the Azure AD group. Now, I need to update the currently logged-in user property under Azure AD. Below is my code snippet,

```
import { graph } from "@pnp/graph";

 public async UpdateCurrentUserProperties(companyName) {
    return await graph.me.update({
        companyName: companyName
    });
}
```

Below is the reference link,
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/users/#update-current-user

I am facing the below error while updating the currently logged-in user profile properties under Azure AD.

> Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration

Can anyone help me with the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "***Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects or objects currently undergoing migration***" usually occurs if you are trying to update the users which synced from on-premises to Azure AD.

- You have to update these users on on-premises environment and then sync it to Azure.
- ***To resolve the error***, Try changing it on On-prem server and then sync it to Azure AD.
- Please check if your organization uses a hybrid environment and those users are synced from AD, you have to manage them from **on-premises Exchange.**
- Check whether you have given required **API permissions**.
- You can [**refer**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-update-user-profile-picture-using-pnp-js-in-spfx#:%7E:text=Open%20a%20developer%20tool%20%28F12%29%20%3E%20Go%20to,profile%20picture%20of%20current%20logged%20in%20user%20*/) this similar case that can give you some pointer.

For more in detail, please find below **links**:

[azure - Set-AzureADuser failing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64543331/set-azureaduser-failing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Unable to update the specified properties for on-premises mastered Directory Sync objects - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/777914/unable-to-update-the-specified-properties-for-on-p.html)